# jquery & facebox image issue problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using facebox first time but the problem is facebox dialog is showing but images is not showing for loadingImage and closeImage.

i specify the images path like

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.facebox.settings.loadingImage = 'images/loading.gif';
    $.facebox.settings.closeImage = 'images/closelabel.gif';
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnFeedback").click(function () {
        $.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.5
        jQuery.facebox('OK, you can close me now');
        return false;
    })

});
```

but why it is not showing. do i need to do anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon on the facebox.settings.opacity line.

Shouldn't this be:

```
$.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.5;
```

I'm not sure if this would affect the loading and close behavior though.

Comment: Are you sure that your image path is correct? Try accessing these images using those urls.